# What triggers the google appscript onFormSubmit event when form reponses are sent to a google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

What actually triggers the google appscript onFormSubmit event when form reponses are sent to a google sheet?

Asking because when looking at the [google API example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms) for handling form responses, they use a linked sheet and monitor submit event from there

```js
ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').forSpreadsheet(ss).onFormSubmit().create();
```

The onFormSubmit submit is linked to the sheet, but the object is a sheet, so does entering any data into the sheet itself count or is it only from the Form that is linked to the Sheet? If I wanted to reference the form by ID, would I use the [Form ID](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app?hl=en#openbyidid) or the linked [Sheet ID](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app?hl=en#openbyidid)? Would the event data still be the same?

Any docs as to what is going on under the surface that could help clarify how this works?

Comment: There is an onsubmit trigger for the form and for the spreadsheet. The onFormSubmit trigger is tied to a function in either or both the form and the spreadsheet.  The trigger is created when a form makes a submission.  Each trigger has a different event block that is the one for the form is different than the one for the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an onformsubmit trigger for the form and another one for the spreadsheet.
The onFormSubmit trigger for the form is tied to a function in the Forms script editor and it's triggered on a form submission.

[onFormSubmit Trigger for form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1)

The onFormSubmit Trigger for the spreadsheet is tied to a function in the script editor of the spreadsheet where the linked sheet is contained and it also triggers on a form submission.  The trigger for the spreadsheet occurs after the linked sheet receives it's data.

[onFormSubmit Trigger for Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)